# React Navigation | [eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token = | React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm having a linting issue with the Air Bnb eslint ruleset, this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class HomePage extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Whats on',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#1980F5',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Insert HomePage</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default HomePage;
```

after navigationOption it doesn't like the "=" (line 9) and shows the message in the title. Everything works like it should but i would like to know how i can get rid of the ESlint error without disabling the rule.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/589 this is still intended behaviour but can be resolved by adding the [`babel-eslint` parser](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) and [transform](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/589#issuecomment-228969436).

In your `.eslintrc` add

```
{
  ...
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "settings": {
    ...
    "import/parser": "babel-eslint",
  }
  ...
}
```

If you'd like to avoid this you could also add the value as a property on the class.

```
class Example {}
Example.staticProp = 'value';
```